# Ruby net/ping returning false for google? (Works from command-line)

Tags: ruby, networking, ping

I can ping google from my local machine, but can anyone tell me why I might be getting "false" when I run the following in IRB on the same machine? Really frustrating as a ping is supposed to be the most simple network op and I just can't get it to work!

```
1.9.2-p290 :001 > require "net/ping"
 => true 
1.9.2-p290 :003 > pinger = Net::Ping::External.new("http://www.google.com")
 => #<Net::Ping::External:0x88eac30 @host="http://www.google.com", @port=7, @timeout=5, @exception=nil, @warning=nil, @duration=nil> 
1.9.2-p290 :004 > pinger.ping
 => false 
1.9.2-p290 :005 >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is *not* a valid [host/domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) (although it is a valid [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)):

```
http://www.google.com
```

Thus, the DNS resolution will fail and, having no target IP, no ping can be sent.

I'm sure you didn't use that *exact* [host](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-ping/1.5.2/Net/Ping#host-instance_method) for the command-line `ping` :) As Gareth notes, doing so would look similar to:

```
$ ping http://www.google.com
ping: cannot resolve http://www.google.com: Unknown host
```

A ["normal ping"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping), which is being attempted here, and an "HTTP ping" are different. Contrast this usage with [`Net::Ping::HTTP`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-ping/1.5.2/Net/Ping/HTTP), which *does* take a URL, for instance.

Happy coding.

---

(Either "google.com" or "www.google.com" would be suitable host names.)

Comment: `$ ping http://www.google.com # => ping: cannot resolve http://www.google.com: Unknown host`

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to check if a site is up then I wouldn't use ping. Ping will tell you if the host is up (unless a router or firewall is blocking ICMP), but it won't tell you if your web server or web app is responding properly.

If that's the case, I'd recommend Net::HTTP from the standard library, or any of the other HTTP libraries. One way to do it is:

```
def up?(site)
  Net::HTTP.new(site).head('/').kind_of? Net::HTTPOK
end

up? 'www.google.com' #=> true
```